# Javascript: Separate a string with 2 values

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript and i have following problem:

in an alert popup i'm getting back a variable with 2 values which are separated by ",".

alert example: 1,2

now i want to get this values separated so i get 2 different variables

value 1 = 1

value 2 = 2

when there is no value
alert example: ,2
then it should look like this:
value 1 = 0
value 2 = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which will split the string into `array` using mentioned `separator`

> [`expr1 || expr2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) => Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

```js
var data = ',2';
var splitted = data.split(',');
alert(splitted[0] || 0);
alert(splitted[1] || 0);
```